# Oracle 19c Installer Can't Select National Character Set

Tags: oracle, character-set, oracle-19c

I am trying to install a new 19c instance of Oracle database in order to migrate a 12c database there. The 12c database uses a database character set of `WE8ISO8859P1` and a national character set of `AL16UTF16`, both configured on installation.

I have found during the 19c installation, however, that there is no option to set the national character set. How can I be sure that this is configured to the correct AL16UTF16?

Answer (score 1):

Just install the DB software then use DBCA to create the database.
There you can choose the national characterset.

Typically noone uses the installer to create a database. Some others (including me) avoid even DBCA.

[image]